# android coordinator layout how to use?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

The above error appears and the app does not run. I googled enough, but everyone told me to check gradle or there was only an example of the old version, so I had no choice but to post a question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".scenarios.sample.view.fragment.SampleFragment">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="sampleViewModel"
            type="com.project.viewmodel.SampleViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@={sampleViewModel.sampleText}"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_sample_test"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:text="Button"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:onSafeClick="@{()-> sampleViewModel.sampleBtnClickEvent()}" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

my gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

I have no idea what the problem is, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try implementing `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theme xml was the problem I dealt with the style

Answer (score 0):

Try  This:

```
    def materialVersion='1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```